# why does datagridview disappear after refreshing twice?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

on form load, my datagridview display a datatable. once the user clicks the delete button, it deletes one of the rows in the data source:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 selectedRowCount =
        dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
            if (selectedRowCount == 1)
            {


                    qResults.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                    chart1.DataSource = qResults;
                    InitializeChart();

                    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                    dataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = qResults;


            }
        }
```

the first time i click this button, it works. it deletes the datapoint from the source and refreshes the chart. however, the second time i click it, it completely wipes out the datagridview and display NOTHING. **but please note that the chart displays correctly**

anyone know what am i donig wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried commenting out the chart code entirely and seeing if your datagridview still shows the same behavior?

Also: what is qResults? The type isn't clear here. If you use a data source like BindingSource, you may not need to reset the datagridview's data source and clear its bindings and columns; the BindingSource with the datagridview takes care of that for you.

If qResults is a DataTable, try using a BindingSource. Set the DataTable as the BindingSource's data source, then set the BindingSource as the datagridview's data source, then see what happens with your delete.

Lastly, do you have explicit databinding code somewhere or do you have datagridview column auto-generate on?

Comment: pelaz: datagridviews do not have bindingsource, this is winform

Comment: @pelaz i do have explicit binding like this dataGridView1.DataSource = qResults;

Comment: @i am a girl:  Are you sure about DGVs not having a BindingSource?  It's not *required* but using a BindingSource does make data-binding *much* easier (as does the drag-and-drop editor...).  System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource -- check it out:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx

Comment: @austin datagridview1.bindingsource -- does not exist

Comment: @i am a girl:  Your DataSource would be the BindingSource.  There's an example in the link I posted here...

Comment: BindingSource foo = new BindingSource();  foo.DataSource = myRawDataSource;   myDGV.DataSource = foo;

HTH

Comment: @pelazem please dont call me a fool

Comment: Not calling you anything; I put in a basic code sample with programmer-typical sample variable "foo" (programmers often use "foo", "bar", "baz", and so on).